# Android: linking to opencv results in SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment) when exception is thrown

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, clang, c++17

I have to work with opencv in an android project. Everything worked fine until I recently had to use c++ exception_ptr as well.
Since then, the use of `std::rethrow_exception` causes a SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment).

I created a minimal example to illustrate the problem. The example application only links to opencv 3.4.4 but does not use any opencv function. If you remove the linking to opencv in `CMakeLists.txt` the app works fine and doesn't crash. If you add it however, the app will crash as soon as the native method `triggerException()` is called.
In my implementation the example application calls this method if a button is pressed.

**native-lib.cpp:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>  
#include <exception>

/* 
 * code based on: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr 
 */

std::string handle_eptr2(std::exception_ptr eptr)
{
    try {
        if (eptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        return "Caught exception \"" + std::string(e.what()) + "\"\n";
    }

    return "Something went wrong";
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_user_exceptiontest_MainActivity_triggerException(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    std::exception_ptr eptr;
    try {
        std::string().at(1); // this generates an std::out_of_range
    } catch(...) {
        eptr = std::current_exception(); // capture
    }

    std::string res = handle_eptr2(eptr);

    return env->NewStringUTF(res.c_str());
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(OPENCV_DIR $ENV{HOME}/lib/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk )

include_directories(${OPENCV_DIR}/native/jni/include )

add_library( native-lib
        SHARED
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)  

find_library( log-lib
        log)

target_link_libraries( 
        native-lib
        # Removing the following line will make everything work as expected (what() message is returned)
        ${OPENCV_DIR}/native/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so # <--- critical line

        ${log-lib})
```

**build.gradle**

To use exceptions and c++17 support, I added the following lines to the configuration that is created by android-studio.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang',
                  '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
        cppFlags "-std=c++1z -frtti -fexceptions"
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
<unknown> 0x004c4e47432b2b01
___lldb_unnamed_symbol15856$$libopencv_java3.so 0x0000007f811c4a58
_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow 0x0000007f811c4fc8
__cxa_rethrow 0x0000007f81181e50
__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() 0x0000007f811b1580
__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) 0x0000007f81181c54
std::terminate() 0x0000007f81181cc0
std::rethrow_exception(std::exception_ptr) 0x0000007f802db2cc
handle_eptr2(std::exception_ptr) native-lib.cpp:35
::Java_com_example_user_exceptiontest_MainActivity_triggerException(JNIEnv *, jobject) native-lib.cpp:58
```

While searching for a solution I looked at the opencv sources (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp) and stumbled upon this code snippet:

```
#ifndef CV__EXCEPTION_PTR
#  if defined(__ANDROID__) && defined(ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE) && ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE < 2
# define CV__EXCEPTION_PTR 0  // Not supported, details: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58938
```

I'd understand if this changes the behavior of opencv, but I don't get how this might influence code that does not use opencv at all.

EDIT: It is also worth mentioning that linking to opencv has no impact if I use this code directly (without jni) in a linux (x86_64) desktop setting (clang, libc++, opencv3.4.4). Thus, my conclusion that it is an android specific problem...

Does anyone has an idea how to solve that issue or what to try next?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Opencv is compiled with gnu runtime while you are using c++ stl. See [One STL per app](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support). You will need to either use gnustl (you will need to go back to ndk 15 for that) or build opencv with c++ stl.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! It took me quite some time to build opencv with c++ stl, but now it is working. I don't get why it wasn't a problem on my desktop computer though. If you want. you can post your comment as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opencv is compiled with gnu runtime while you are using c++ stl. See [One STL per app](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support). You will need to either use gnustl (you will need to go back to ndk 15 for that) or build opencv with c++ stl.

In order to build opencv with c++_static you can try to follow [comment in opencv bugtracker](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8742#issuecomment-385553011)

> cmake -GNinja -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=ON
>   -DANDROID_EXAMPLES_WITH_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DWITH_IPP=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
>   -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static" -DANDROID_ABI=x86 -DANDROID_SDK_TARGET=18 ../opencv

Followed by

> make && make install